# Topbar cannot rotate in landscape view with storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have just converted from .nib files to storyboard, but suddenly the view wont rotate topbar in landscape view. All the settings are "inferred" in my view, and i have not really made any changes since the conversion.

Is this a common problem when upgrading? I have not found any specific info.

And furthermore i do not force any view rotations in my code.

If any more info is needed i can supply anything!

Thanks in advance.

ViewController:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
}
```

Comment: What's a _topbar_? Do you mean navigation bar (the bar on top) or rather tab bar (the bar on the bottom)?

Comment: It could be a navigation bar, but since im not using that in this application its only the "status bar" where the battery status is located. Hence i refer to it as a topbar.

Comment: Right, that one slipped my mind :)

Comment: 20 definitions, but only 1 meaning.. Its not an easy task :o)

Comment: I'm not aware of any known issues when moving from nibs to storyboard. I did it once and it just worked. You can always create a new project with a storyboard and verify that settings in broken project are correct.

Comment: I think that has to be my last resort to resolve the issue..

Comment: I tried to look at another sample but still no luck. My code is located here, incase you could spot a mistake: https://github.com/maziarzamani/AC3D_Demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look at your code and you seem to be missing a method that allows your view controller to rotate freely.

Subclass UIViewController e.g. like this:

```
// .h file
@interface OrientationAwareViewController : UIViewController
@end

// m.file
@implementation OrientationAwareViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Then set `OrientationAwareViewController` in the storyboard as your main view controller's class name. That said, I have no idea how this worked for you when using nibs :) [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says clearly:

> By default, this method returns `YES` for the `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` orientation only. If your view controller supports additional orientations, override this method and return `YES` for all orientations it supports.

Comment: Thanks alot! I dont know how i missed that completely!

Comment: Only issue now is that the OpenGL view is stretching depending on landscape or portrait.

Comment: Then you can set OpenGL view frame to, say, 1024x1024 and its autoresizing mask to `UIViewAutoresizingNone`. Maybe this helps...

Comment: Right i think the issue os something else right now. drawView only gets called when i change orientation. Somethings clearly wrong now.

Comment: `autoresizesSubviews` is a `BOOL` property, so possible values are `YES` and `NO`. On my computer `drawView` is called right after application launch... It's not possible to set custom size to the root view of the view controller in storyboard, but instead you can use `UIView` as a root view and add `EAGLView` as its child and it would work.

Comment: So my delegate animates/updates the view? Right now its frozen.